# Is it in ruby bad practice to not do a type check before doing RARRAY_PTR for self created variables

Tags: c, ruby

In extensions to ruby RARRAY_PTR() which returns a VALUE* for a given ruby array is dangerous, since it does no type checks. For example this will probably segfault:

```
VALUE a= rb_hash_new();
RARRAY_PTR(a)[999];
```

I sometimes find myself storing an array into an instance variable and then later doing RARRAY_PTR() on this instance variable. This can be dangerous since there are ways to tamper with any objects instance variables. If someone does this, I could be ending up doing RARRAY_PTR() one something which is not an array.

Is it bad pratice to rely on otheres not changing my instance variables, or is it there fault if then the ruby interpreter segfaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it that much. If someone is messing around with your instance variables then they're responsible for whatever damage they cause.

If someone uses [`instance_varible_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) to change an instance variable from an array to a Fixnum in a pure Ruby class, then you'll probably end up with a [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html); if they do it to your C backed class, they'll get a segfault.

Basically, if someone wants to smash themselves in the face with a brick by messing around with an object's internals, then it isn't your problem.

Comment: It's one of the many trade-offs to having a flexible, dynamic runtime. You probably wouldn't type-check the return value of your own methods, but sure, somebody could have overridden those to return something different too.  It's their problem, not yours.

Comment: @d11wtq: Yeah, you pretty much have to trust people to behave themselves or your code will end up as an incomprehensible mess of `kind_of?` and `respond_to?` calls.